# How to make an intuitive form field for a M2M relationship with many options in Django?

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Apologies if the title is poorly worded, I couldn't figure out a succinct way to describe this issue.

I've been working with a client who uses the Django form library to allow users to create/edit model instances. I've recently added a many to many relationship between model A and model B, and I want there to be an input on the model A form that allows users to connect instances of model B to it. The `SelectMultiple` widget used by Django by default is unintuitive, and the alternative `CheckboxSelectMultiple` widget seems like it wouldn't be great once there are 100s of options (which is a likely scenario). What complicates this further is that there's also a M2M relationship between model C and D, connected by a through table that determines a D instance's order on a C instance, and neither of those widgets work well with through tables.

My initial thought was to use `CheckboxSelectMultiple` and just order the already selected options at the top, wrapping the widget in a scroll overflow container. I unfortunately don't know how to order options in that way though, since the accepted `queryset` parameter is inherently unordered. For the case with the through table, ideally each checked option would have an input next to it where users could set the order of the respective instance, but I'm not sure how to fundamentally alter the widget in that way.

So, how would you advise I go about making a form field for a M2M relationship with many options? Is there a way to make my modified `CheckboxSelectMultiple` idea work, or is there an alternative, more efficient way to do this (possibly involving libraries)? I can't imagine I'm the first person to encounter this problem.

Comment: I ll be very honest, I have not read the question complete.
The M2M fields in tables creates a mapping table in background, if you want more control over that, it is always a good idea to manually create the mapping table. with Two Foreign key relations with two models.

Comment: @shivankgtm apologies if I was misleading. of course there's the through table automatically created between model A and model B, but the challenge comes with the custom through table between models C and D, which contains the foreign keys in addition to a numerical field `order`. Ideally I'd like to use the form field to both create the connections between models C and D while also dictating the order. hope this helps!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's "one I wrote earlier" Sorry, this is a bit of an info-dump. Has worked, but not fully tested. Check that it's csrf-safe if you care about that (it doesn't use a form, just picks things out of request.POST)

```
class GenericEditM2MView( DetailView):
    #model = Model         # required as per DetailView
    # template_name =      # as per DetailView
    #m2m_fieldname = None # no longer required if unique: the name of the model's m2m field to operate on
    remove_qs = None     # defaults to .all() of the m2m field
    success_url = '.'    # defaults to displaying the modified m2m relationship unless done
    done_url = None      # where to go if submit="Done", defaults to success_url
# 

    """template_name must define a form full of checkboxes, obtained from
      {% for p in add_qs %}
       <input type="checkbox" name="add" value="{{p.pk}}" > {% endfor}
      {% for p in remove_qs %}
       <input type="checkbox" name="remove " value="{{p.pk}}" > {% endfor}

   default is to return to this same view after submit, to show that the changes
   have been made. You can supply <input type="submit" name="submit" value="done" />
   which will go to done_url instead of success_url

   example use:

    class PenStockM2MView( GenericEditM2MView):
        template_name = 'playpen/edit_m2m.html' 
        model = PenStock
        # m2m_fieldname = 'name' # works it out for itself if ony one M2M field on the model
        done_url = '/playpen/OK'
    """
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(**kwargs)

        # everything works without this __init__ provided self.m2m_fieldname is present and correct.
        # if model has only one m2m field, locate it via _meta as default. 
        # Also check m2m_fieldname is m2m because very confusing errors later if it's not!

        f = getattr(self, 'm2m_fieldname', None)
        m2m_fieldnames = [ 
            field.name for field in self.model._meta.get_fields() if field.many_to_many ]
        model_name = self.model.__name__

        if f and not f in m2m_fieldnames:
            raise AttributeError( f'field "{f}" is not a many-to-many field in {model_name}')

        if not f:
            if len( m2m_fieldnames ) == 1:
                self.m2m_fieldname = m2m_fieldnames[0]
            else:
                raise AttributeError( f'Cannot identify a unique many-to-many field in {model_name}' )      

    def get_add_queryset(self):
        field = getattr( self.object, self.m2m_fieldname)
        remove_qs = self.get_remove_queryset()
        already_there = remove_qs.values_list('pk', flat=True)
        return remove_qs.model.objects.exclude( pk__in = already_there)  # is qs.model documented?

    def get_remove_queryset(self):
        if hasattr( self, 'remove_queryset'):
            return self.remove_qs
        remove_qs = getattr( self.object, self.m2m_fieldname)
        return remove_qs.all()    

    def get_context_data( self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data( **kwargs)
        context['add_qs'] = self.get_add_queryset()
        context['remove_qs'] = self.get_remove_queryset()
        return context

    def post( self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        self.object = self.get_object()
        add = request.POST.getlist('add')
        remove = request.POST.getlist('remove')
        add_objs =    list( self.get_add_queryset().filter(pk__in=add) )
        remove_objs = list(  self.get_remove_queryset().filter(pk__in=remove) )
        field = getattr( self.object, self.m2m_fieldname )
        field.add( *add_objs)
        field.remove( *remove_objs)
        return HttpResponseRedirect( self.get_done_url() or self.get_success_url() )

    def get_success_url(self):
       return self.success_url

    def get_done_url( self):
        done = self.request.POST.get("submit", None)
        if done == "done" and hasattr(self, 'done_url'):
            return self.done_url 
        return None
```

Comment: Thank you! This was a good starting point for me and I incorporated your strategy into my view to achieve the form that I wanted.